# R converting data.frame to zoo

Tags: r, dataframe, zoo

I have a big data.frame where the whole dataset is loaded from a csv. Dates are stored like 20130614 in Column 1, which is in my case MergedSet$Date.

How do I create a zoo object of this whole data.frame? I found some hints in other Posts but I cannot get this working:

```
test<-read.zoo(MergedSet, Format="%y%m%d")
```

Error in read.zoo(...): index has 8206 bad entries at data rows 1,2,3,4,5...

Comment: Try to set `index.column` argument within `read.zoo()`. Otherwise, you surely specify the date format, but R doesn't know which column of your data frame contains the dates.

Comment: Note that R is case-sensitive -- `Format` is not the same as `format`

Comment: ...and to continue @GSee's point, `"%y"` is not the same as `"%Y"`.